# Unable to create Generic Service in cluster using WMI script

Tags: powershell, wmi, cluster-computing, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I want to create a Cluster Generic Service using script. We have Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V. Am using [Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460966.aspx) command Now i am facing 2 problems.

1. When executing it simply with service name I am getting this error
   [image]
2. I provided "-StaticAddress" to the command and then executed again but again getting error
   [image]

Also I am able to create the service from UI using the same cluster disk, IP, etc. I am admin on the server and have full access to cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was.. I removed all the disks from storage and then again added.

Used the same command and it worked

```
Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole -ServiceName "<SERVICE NAME>" -Storage "Cluster Disk <NUMBER>" -Name <CLUSTER NAME> –StaticAddress <IP ADDRESS>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't really an "answer", but it is a list of useful techniques to troubleshoot:

- Can you online the disk with the "Start-ClusterResource" Cmdlet?
- Why is the disk offline in the first place?
- What is in that report file from the second screenshot?
- Are running PowerShell "As Administrator"?
- Is there any information in the Microsoft=>Windows=>FailoverClustering or FailoverClustering-Manager event log?